# How can I prevent the git clean--ffdx command in my yml pipeline in Azure Devops?

Tags: azure-devops

My checkout task is adding the git clean -ffdx command, which makes my pipeline run longer.
[image: azure devops output]

Where does this come from? Is there a way to remove it? Are there parameters from there available for this in yml?

In my yml I'm not setting anything special:

```
resources:
  - repo: self
  
pool:
  name: Mobile
  
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - main
steps:
- template: templates/build-server.yml
```

Comment: What do you mean by "makes my pipeline run longer"? Is the time to run that command on its own too longer or is a clean build longer than one that has previous artifacts around?

Comment: The checkout task runs for 1 min 32. For other pipelines (that don't seem to have the clean command), the checkout task takes a few seconds...

Comment: It's probably in your template. There should be a checkout step where you'll need to specify `clean: ''`.

Comment: Are you talking about this workspace clean parameter? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/phases?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#workspace

Comment: This one - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/steps-checkout?view=azure-pipelines (if it's not there, then probably it's picking up the default value, add something like `- checkout: self\n\tclean: ''` in your steps)

Comment: omg, thank you!